# Send byte[] in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to send data with id,name , and file (PdfBytes) byte[] with ajax to my service.

How can i add my PDF file to var pdf and add it to my ajax.

My code

```
var PdfBytes;
//Tried to fill PdfBytes with get,didnt work
$.get('http://testservices.xxx/PdfService/MYTest.pdf', function(data) 
{
   PdfBytes=data;

});


        var ConvertHtmlToPdfAndSendEmail = {
        "PdfBytes":PdfBytes,
         id": id,
         "Name": name
           };

  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(ConvertHtmlToPdfAndSendEmail),
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "http://testservices.xxx/ConvertHtmlToPdfAndDownload",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    //my code

                },
                error: function (req, err) {
                   //my code
                }
            })
```

In the server i get PdfBytes is null

function expect to get `byte[] PdfBytes`

Sow how i can upload my pdf from my pc to var  PdfBytes ,and send it in ajax to my service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use option call 'async' so do that:

```
var PdfBytes = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://testservices.xxx/PdfService/MYTest.pdf',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false
});

var ConvertHtmlToPdfAndSendEmail = {
    PdfBytes: PdfBytes,
    id: id,
    Name: name
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(ConvertHtmlToPdfAndSendEmail),
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "http://testservices.xxx/ConvertHtmlToPdfAndDownload",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        //my code

    },
    error: function (req, err) {
        //my code
    }
});
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Why should `async: false` help to send parameter?

Comment: From what can not associate so as to assign the variables using ajax and thats why he get null

Answer (score 1):

There two way to send byte[] in Ajax
You convert byte[] to string for GET or to json for POST
=> The main thing you should convert to byte array to text
and recover the data format when call the server script

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://testservices.xxx/ConvertHtmlToPdfAndDownload?data="+encodeURI(byte_array.join())
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(byte_array),
    url: "http://testservices.xxx/ConvertHtmlToPdfAndDownload"
});
```

Hope it help!